# looping over an array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, append, stringbuffer

hello i have previously used this code to loop over my array row by row, however i want to do it column by column now,would the best option be to have two for loops,
i and j and then then append [j] [i]?

```
StringBuffer decryptedText = new StringBuffer();
         for(char [] i : array){
         for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++) {
         if (i[j] !=0){
             decryptedText.append(i[j]);
         }
         }

        }
         decryptedText.toString();
            System.out.println("\nDecrypted Text:\n" + decryptedText );
```

Comment: You should prefer `StringBuilder` to `StringBuffer`, and the `for-each` loop won't be as helpful. Also, you can't get the column count until you're iterating the rows.

Comment: To accept an answer, click the hollowed out heck mark next to the beginning of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will only work if your array is not ragged**

```
StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
int rowLen = array.length;
int colLen = array[0].length;
for(int a=0; a<colLen; a++)
    for(int b=0; b<rowLen; b++)
        if(array[b][a]!=0)
            text.append(array[b][a]);
System.out.println(text.toString());
```

Comment: thanks, new to all this, learning slowly

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments `for-each` wont help you when want to access your multi-dimensional array column wise. Simple `for` loops will do the task.

> Here is an example code snippet

```
void iterateColumnWise() {
    char data[][] = new char[SIZE][];
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<data[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(data[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

> Or You may access a single column data of multi-dimensional array as

```
void iterateColumnWise(int column) {
    char data[][] = new char[SIZE][];
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        System.out.println(data[i][column]);
    }
}
```